# On creating a windows forms app in vb.net in visual studio, there is no design file of the form

Tags: vb.net

[visual studio windows forms app project in vb.net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvMwl.png)

I want to design a form but there is no design file of the form. When i create a forms app project in c#, the design is visible but when done using vb.net, there is no such file.

Comment: It looks like maybe you opened up the code file (.*vb) for the Form directly. You need to open the PROJECT (*.vbproj) or SOLUTION (*.sln) file.

Comment: What do you mean by "design file"? If you mean that you want to open the form in the designer then you simply double-click it in the Solution Explorer. If you're doing that and it's opening a code window instead of a design window then there's an issue but we don't know that you've done that.

Comment: If you're still not sure, please provide a screenshot of your Solution Explorer window. Make sure that the project node is expanded. Also, click the *Show All Files* button and expand the form node too.

Comment: The problem appears to be that your VS Solution is completely empty. There is no Project nor Form. Add a new WinForms project to the solution. Then you can start working with the given Form1.

Answer (score 0):

Press **Shift + F7** to enter the design mode and **F7** to return back to the code